# How to pass mixed parameters for an AWS Step Functions state machine

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-step-functions

I have an AWS Step Functions  state machine defined in a json file, in `step1` (a lambda task), I saved three parameters in the `ResultPath`:

```
   "NeededParameters": {
      "year": "2021",
      "month": "04",
      "day": "27"
    },
```

In `step2` (also a lambda task), I understand that if I do something like:

```
"Step 2" : {
         "Type": "Task",
         "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
         "Parameters": {
             "FunctionName":"${lambda_name}",
             "Payload":{
               "year.$": "$.NeededParameters.year"
             }
         },
         "ResultPath": "$.Step2",
```

`"year.$": "$.NeededParameters.year"` will pass `2021` to payload `Year`.

But what I want to achieved is to define an Amazon S3 path which includes the three parameters, something like:

```
 "Step 2" : {
          "Type": "Task",
          "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
          "Parameters": {
              "FunctionName":"${lambda_name}",
              "Payload":{
                "s3path.$":"${s3_bucket_name}/$.NeededParameters.year/$.NeededParameters.month/$.NeededParameters.day"
              }
          },
          "ResultPath": "$.Step2",
```

`s3_bucket_name` is defined in Terraform `resource "aws_sfn_state_machine" "sfn_state_machine"` and pass to the statemachine definition json file above, but when I apply terraform it complains:

```
InvalidDefinition: Invalid State Machine Definition: 'SCHEMA_VALIDATION_FAILED: The value for the field 's3path.$' must be a valid JSONPath at /States/Process Scores/Parameters'
```

if I change `s3path.$` to `s3path` it still not working, does anyone know how to resolve this? Thanks.

Comment: Could you possibly edit your question so that it forms an [mcve] please? This makes it much easier to be able to provide answers that might be reliant on other parts of it and also makes it easier for people to see exactly what you've tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. As the error message implies, the string you pass to `s3path.$` is not valid JSONPath. If you want to pass some static value, you need to name it without `.$` at the end (simply `s3path`), otherwise, like in your case, it will be treated and validated as a JSONPath.
2. Static params don't support any kind of string expansion to my knowledge, especially involving JSONPath. I would suggest passing param called `s3BucketName` in addition to year, month and day, and then simply construct S3 URL inside lambda function itself.

Comment: Hi thanks, for the 2nd point, 'construct S3 URL inside lambda function' I guess I can do that but that probably won't work because I want to have a dynamic s3 url (pass the current date everyday). For the first point, if I define as `s3path` and without `$` then I can't pass the values from `$.NeededParameters.xxx`, I'm a bit stuck on this, or maybe I'm in the completely wrong direction...

Comment: @Cecilia why would you *pass* current date? Why not use datetime lib of whatever language you use and determine date inside function as well? Also JSONPath parameters are local to each invokation, while static params are always the same

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```json
{
   "Step 2" : {
          "Type": "Task",
          "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
          "InputPath": "$.NeededParameters",
          "Parameters": {
              "FunctionName":"${lambda_name}",
              "Payload":{
                "s3path.$": "States.Format('{}/{}/{}/{}', ${s3_bucket_name}, $.year, $.month, $.day)"
              }
          },
          "ResultPath": "$.Step2"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer [@wawawa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10581944/wawawa):

> Hi thanks, for the 2nd point, 'construct S3 URL inside lambda function' I guess I can do that but that probably won't work because I want to have a dynamic s3 url (pass the current date everyday). For the first point, if I define as s3path and without $ then I can't pass the values from $.NeededParameters.xxx, I'm a bit stuck on this, or maybe I'm in the completely wrong direction...

You can use the Intrinsic Function of the states language, called States.Format:
https://states-language.net/#appendix-b